# Find matching string occurrence in an ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList<String>` containing dates represented as Strings with the format `yyyy-MM-dd`, e.g:

```
ArrayList<String> dates = new ArrayList<>(); 
dates.add("1991-02-28");
dates.add("1991-02-28");
dates.add("1994-02-21");
```

I'd like to know the number of times the same `String` (date) appears in the list. In the example above, I'd like to achieve the following output:

```
1991-02-28, 2
1994-02-21, 1
```

I've tried the following code

```
    ArrayList<String> dates = new ArrayList<>();
    dates.add("1991-02-28");
    dates.add("1991-02-28");
    dates.add("1994-02-21");
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
    HashMap<String, String> dateCount = new HashMap<String, String>();

    String first = dates.get(0);
    int count = 1;
    dateCount.put(first, String.valueOf(count));
    for (int i = 1; i < dates.size(); i++) {
        if (first.equals(dates.get(i))) {
            count++;
        } else {
            first = dates.get(i);
            dateCount.put(dates.get(i), String.valueOf(count));
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    for (String date : dates) {
        String occ = dateCount.get(date);
        System.out.println(date + ", " + occ);
    }
```

But it prints

```
1991-02-28, 1
1991-02-28, 1
1994-02-21, 2
```

I'm tired, stuck, and turning to SO as a last resort. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I might have formulated my problem badly. What I'd like to print is `1991-02-28, 2` and `1994-02-21, 1` @AmirAfghani

Comment: I see your edit now.  So, effectively this is a groupBy operation.  Are you using Java 8?  Guava also has a method that does this for you..

Comment: Precisely, groupBy would solve it. Unfortunately I'm currently using Java 7. @AmirAfghani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all that is required is just a count of the number of occurrences of each **full** string in a `List<String>` collection, there are numerous trivial ways in `Java 7` (or earlier) for doing it - not necessarily the fastest ones, but working.

For example, one can create a `Set` from the list and iterate over all items in the set, calling [`Collections.frequency(list, item)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency%28java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Object%29), where `list` is the `List<String>` collection and `item` is each string of the set iteration.

Here is a simple implementation:

```
  public static class FrequencyCount {
    public static void main(String[] args){
      java.util.ArrayList<String> dates = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
      dates.add("1991-02-28");
      dates.add("1991-02-28");
      dates.add("1994-02-21");
      java.util.Set<String> uniqueDates = new java.util.HashSet<String>(dates);
      for (String date : uniqueDates) {
        System.out.println(date + ", " + java.util.Collections.frequency(dates, date));
      }
    }
  }
```

**Output:**

```
1994-02-21, 1
1991-02-28, 2
```

Comment: This is a very clean solution which is working as intended, thank you.

Comment: `Collections.frequency()` is an O(n) operation, meaning this solution is O(n^2).  Every other answer contains an O(n) solution; this is *not* how you want to do this.

Comment: Sure. I would also suggest a map-based solution like yours as a better alternative. This one was the simplest to demonstrate a working result and the question does not appear to be large-scale, or require high performance, hence I preferred the simplest approach. I have already given you a +1 since yesterday, by the way. :-)

Comment: I'm not quite sure that I follow. Could you elaborate on why this answer is inferior to the others? I used a TreeSet instead of a HashSet, if that changes anything :-) @ dimo414

Comment: @Marcus `TreeSet` vs. `HashSet` is irrelevant (though `TreeSet` is O(log n) on most operations, making it generally worse than `HashSet`).  The issue here is that `Collections.frequency()` is being called `n` times, and it has to iterate over the whole `dates` list each time in order to count each element.  That's O(n^2) time.  Using a `Multiset` or `Map<T, Integer>` will do the same work in O(n) time.

Answer (score 3):

I may be missing something, but it looks like you could just do something simple like this, just keep the count of Dates in the HashMap, and iterate over the HashMap for the output:

```
    ArrayList<String> dates = new ArrayList<>();
    dates.add("1991-02-28");
    dates.add("1991-02-28");
    dates.add("1994-02-21");
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
    HashMap<String, Integer> dateCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < dates.size(); i++) {

        String date = dates.get(i);
        Integer count = dateCount.get(date);
        if (count == null){
          dateCount.put(date, 1);
        }
        else{
          dateCount.put(date, count + 1);
        }

    }
    for(String key : dateCount.keySet()){
        Integer occ = dateCount.get(key);
        System.out.println(key + ", " + occ);
    }
```

Output:

```
1991-02-28, 2
1994-02-21, 1
```

Comment: you aren't missing anything - i did the same thing and got the same results.  this or an api are the right answer here.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't debugged your logic yet, but you can use Google Guava's [index](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#index%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) method to perform a groupBy.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the correct solution:

public class mainClass {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ArrayList<String> dates = new ArrayList<>();
    dates.add("1991-02-28");
    dates.add("1991-02-28");
    dates.add("1994-02-21");
    //SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
    HashMap<String, Integer> dateCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    //          String first = dates.get(0);
    //          int count = 1;
    //          dateCount.put(first, String.valueOf(count));
    //          for (int i = 1; i < dates.size(); i++) {
    //              if (first.equals(dates.get(i))) {
    //                  count++;
    //              } else {
    //                  first = dates.get(i);
    //                  dateCount.put(dates.get(i), String.valueOf(count));
    //                  count = 0;
    //              }
    //          }

    for(int i= 0; i < dates.size();i++) 
    {
        if(dateCount.containsKey(dates.get(i)))
        {
            dateCount.put(dates.get(i),dateCount.get(dates.get(i))+1); 
        }
        else 
            dateCount.put(dates.get(i),1); 
    }
    for (String date : dates) {
        int occ = dateCount.get(date);
        System.out.println(date + ", " + occ);
    }

}
```

}

But, you need to traverse through the hashmap instead of ArrayList to get the desired ouput..

Hope This helps!

Answer (score 2):

The data structure you're describing is commonly called a [Multiset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) or Bag (and generally uses `Integer` as the value, not `String`).

[Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) provides a very nice [`Multiset`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) interface, which makes this operation trivial:

```
Multiset<String> counts = HashMultiset.create();
for(String date : dates) {
  counts.add(date);
}
System.out.println(counts);
```

> ```
> [1991-02-28 x 2, 1994-02-21]
> ```

Even without Guava, you can fake a Multiset with a `Map<T, Integer>` and a little boilerplate:

```
Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();
for(String date : dates) {
  Integer count = counts.get(date);
  if(count == null) {
    count = 0;
  }
  counts.put(date, count+1);
}
System.out.println(counts);
```

> ```
> {1991-02-28=2, 1994-02-21=1}
> ```